# Why is jQuery toggle() executing when not called

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm using Ajax to create a table, some columns are visible some are not visible.

I know there are a lot of ways to do things, below is how I'm doing it.

The '17' in the code below represents one value from a cookie set when optional columns are desired. On initial load of the table the cookie is read and any columns listed in the cookie are toggled on. This part works just fine.

Any edit to the Ajax table causes a refresh of the table resetting it to its original state, which hides column 17. This means the cookie must be referenced again to determine what the user wants to see, and the column has to be toggled again. This is the part not working so good. On the table load everything works fine, on the first table refresh and all subsequent table refreshes I can never get column 17 to toggle back on after the first refresh turned it off.

As far as I can tell the toggle() is happening regardless of the current visible state of column 17.
This is the code I'm using to test and toggle.

```
if (sh == '17') { 
  if ($(".toggleCNTY").is(':visible' )) {
    // 'true' So do Nothing because this its already visible
  } else if (!$(".toggleCNTY").is(':visible' )) { 
    // 'false' So toggle it to be visible
    $(".toggleCNTY").toggle();  
  }
}
```

Despite the fact that I can verify that the code only gets into each of the if and else loops as it should, in the end another toggle happens when the column is already visible.

Does someone see a reason for this?

Comment: Looks like somewhere you are calling this code twice. Could you add the rest of your code please.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd recommend you to simplify your code, removing unecessary logic, like this:

```
if (sh === '17' && !$(".toggleCNTY").is(':visible')) {
    $(".toggleCNTY").toggle();
}
```

Although I don't think this alone is going to solve your problem. You could check, in the browser console, the element's display property. It seems that the function is('visible') is always returning false. If so, you could test the element's visibility or display and use it in your logic:

```
const isCNTYHidden = $(".toggleCNTY").css('visibility') === 'hidden' || $(".toggleCNTY").css('display') === 'none';

if (sh === '17' && isCNTYHidden) {
    $(".toggleCNTY").toggle();
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the 'const' you gave but in I see that its value is always 'false'. If I put both you pieces of code together then it indeed makes the hidden column visible. On the refresh it hides it but only after what seems to be a flash of it making it visible. If you blink you miss it. The would seems to indicate its being set to hidden someplace else but I don't use the toggle code anywhere else in the program. Thoughts?

Comment: On the initial display of the table isCNTYHidden = false. And the column is toggled to show. On the refresh of the table isCNTYHidden = false again but this time the column is hidden.   My Code:                                           if (sh === '17' && !$(".toggleCNTY").is(':visible')) {
  //alert("in first test");
     $(".toggleCNTY").toggle();
 } 
 

 const isCNTYHidden = $(".toggleCNTY").css('visibility') === 'hidden' || $(".toggleCNTY").css('display') === 'none';
 alert("isCNTYHidden= "+isCNTYHidden);

 if (sh === '17' && isCNTYHidden) {
     $(".toggleCNTY").toggle();
 }

Comment: #CristianoSoares In short, I don't understand how to use both parts of your suggestion together. I really like the simplified code and it works great. I now understand what 'const' is, but near as I can tell it changes between the initial display of the window and the refresh of the table.

Comment: @KeithDKaiser, you should not use both logics together as long as they are meant to get the same result. The first one uses the jQuery method 'is' to check the element's visibility. The second one checks its visibility directly in its style properties. I've changed my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: #CristianoSoares thanks for the clarification. I actually tried that before but the column is still being re-hidden on the refresh. The issue may be related to the difference between the Windows refresh and the table refresh by Ajax.